# How to create a workspace in CodeBlocks?

Tags: codeblocks

Hello i am not able to *create a workspace in codeblocks*, one *that i can share with somebody else*. On my computer works but when i send it to somebody else the paths are not right. They are only for my specific path. I don't find any tutorial on this topic.

When I double click on my `.workspace` file, I got the error:

> Unable to open `folder_name\file_name.cbp`

Comment: I don't have CodeBlocks handy, hence a comment and not an answer: On your computer, where your project works, open the project config file (presumably `.workspace`) and replace any absolute path with relative paths (relative to the workspace folder). This should work.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that and as soon as i figure out how, i will provide pictures and step by step instructions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you first open the **CodeBlocks** an empty workspace will be shown in the `Projects` tab of the `Management` window.

[image: empty workspace]

As you follow the instructions:

> File >> New >> Projects... >> Console application (for example)

the projects will appear under the `Workspace` text. This means that the files that you now create or add, will be part of the same `Workspace`.

[image: workspace populated]

After finishing adding projects:

> Right click on `workspace` >> Save workspace as... >> **select the folder where your projects belogs to**

The default place where `CodeBlocks` automatically saves the workspace is (for Win) `C:\Users\usr_name\AppData\Roaming\CodeBlocks`, so take care where do you save the file. You **SHOULD** save this in the same folder where your projects are.

[image: save workspace as]